# How can I use a generic interface to enhance an existing interface with additional value types?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to build a generic interface so that it can extend the allowed value types of a given interface. I try to illustrate this below....

If I have an interface as below...

```
interface Original {
  prop1: string
  prop2: number
}
```

How can I build a generic interface, let's say ExtraValueTypes<T> so that the result is as below?

```
type ExtraType = myType

interface WithExtraValueTypes {
  prop1: string | myType
  prop2: number | myType
}

such that...

ExtraValueTypes<Original> = WithExtraValueTypes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of mapped types as below. All you need to a map definition that unions all the properties with Extra type.

```js
interface Original {
  prop1: string
  prop2: number
}

type Extra = { a: string }

type Extrator<T> ={
    [P in keyof T] : T[P] | Extra
}

type ExtraOriginal = Extrator<Original>;

const sample: ExtraOriginal ={
    prop1: { a: "foo" },
    prop2 :3
}

const sample2: ExtraOriginal ={
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2 :{a:"bar"}
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJWAc1HANsgbwChlkAHKAezIEYAuZAZzAxExPKrICYGQBXALYAjaEQC+RImACeZFAFEAHizjIAvIWRwGzVpmSTpcxSqhwwlKAB4AKgD4NxUqQDaABWShkAawgzKGGRbAF1kBlsPMIAfZGVVCSlZeTizOHQsHHxNePNLGwzsEDx7AG4pBEoQZiY4QTJcCAZc9IwivCcOUgpqei0dZAAiGEpKQcMAGi7Oam5wgGZEokrqsFr6xt5U1UKszpcZ2gZh0cGpg56ecIIdQeE4KEHJcSA)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was missing the `T[P]` syntax - didn't know I could do that. Really handy.